Having a class with a variable View doesn't work in SwiftUI
I have a class with a variable. I want to store different views in it (TextView, ImageView etc)
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let testClass = TestClass()
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            testClass.testView
        }
 
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    
    var text: String = "test1"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
    }
}


class TestClass {
    var testView: View = TextView()
}

This doesn't work with var testView: View but would work with var testView: TextView
I try to understand why because TextView is a View ?
And I try to understand how to solve the problem because I want to use different custom views in my variable.

It is unlikely that you should ever be “storing” a View. You may want to check out Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC.

Maybe your ContentView should be generic instead

View structs can't make objects like that it's a memory leak
